# Update entire HTML table column using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want to update entire column with new_data

I tried to update as bellows

```
 response.json().then(function (new_data){
        console.log(new_data)
       
        var body_data = " ";

        new_data.forEach((item) => {
        var list_data = "";
        list_data += "<td>" + item.vc_state + "</td>";
        body_data += list_data;
        });

        $('#vc_state').html(body_data);  })
```

But it update only the cell as bellows
[image]

I want to update entire **State** column with new data

**Please help me to solve this**

## Updated

I updated as follows

```
 response.json().then(function (data){
        console.log(data)
        var body_data = " ";
        data.forEach((item) => {
        var list_data = "";
        list_data += "<td>" + item.vc_state + "</td>";
        $('#vc_state').replaceWith(list_data);
      });
```

It worked. But it changed the **HTML only once** . I need to update HTML when I call the function without refreshing the page

Comment: Can you share the HTML for `vc_state`

Comment: This question needs to ideally include the HTML layout and setup for the HTML table, if you can provide that snippet in this question, it would help us try come up with a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

watch table infor with w3c will help you. table>thead|tbody>tr>td|th.

Comment: Can you please give more details

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table